# How to identify indexes of elements appearing only once in a vector in R?

Tags: r, unique

I would like to have logical vector which identifies positions of elements only appearing once in a column of a data frame.

As far as I understood `unique()` and `duplicated()` base R functions cannot be of help, as they either show duplicate-removed list of values or positions of duplicates.

The use of a `table()` function may identify values occuring once but not their position to be used for further data manipulation. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: Use the `which(!(duplicated(v1)|duplicated(v1, fromLast=TRUE)))`

Comment: Try `ave(x, x, FUN = length) > 1`

Comment: `setdiff(unique(x),x[duplicated(x)])`

Answer (score 3):

Let `x` be your vector, for example :

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:10, 10 ,replace = T)
```

You can do it in two steps :

```
var.names <- names(table(x))[table(x) == 1]
match(var.names, x)
```

To get `var.names`you can also do :

```
names(which(table(x) == 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers here. I thought I'd compare their computation time

```
x <- rbinom(500, 1000, 0.5)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  x[which(!(duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE)))], 
  x[ave(x, x, FUN = length) == 1], 
  setdiff(unique(x),x[duplicated(x)]), 
  names(which(table(x) == 1))
)
```

The output is

```
Unit: microseconds
                                                        expr     min       lq      mean  median
 x[which(!(duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)))]  22.517  26.2880  28.75954  29.460
                             x[ave(x, x, FUN = length) == 1] 247.923 256.4725 265.80232 262.290
                        setdiff(unique(x), x[duplicated(x)])  38.706  41.1915  45.58309  46.278
                                 names(which(table(x) == 1)) 194.656 204.4935 213.87719 213.388
      uq     max neval  cld
  31.036  41.033   100 a   
 266.321 461.379   100    d
  48.546  71.819   100  b  
 219.536 290.785   100   c
```

So the winner is `x[which(!(duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE)))]`